# Magento 2 validate filesize

Tags: magento-2.1

In magento 2 how can i validate filesize, i added following code in my grid, but its not working. Is there any way to achieve this:-

```
 $fieldset->addField(
            'uploaded_file', 'file', [
            'name' => 'uploaded_file',
            'label' => __('Attachment'),
            'title' => __('Attachment'),
            'required' => $requireFlag,
            'note' => $displayNotify,
            'value' => $model->getUploadedFile(),
            'validate_class' => 'validate-filesize'
            ]
        );
```